# Why are human.x=10 and human.test(0) compile error in Java with anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, class, oop, compiler-errors, anonymous-class

```
class Human {

    void eat() {
        System.out.println("human eat!");
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human = new Human() {
            int x = 10;

            public void test() {
                System.out.println("test - anonymous");
            }

            @Override
            void eat() {
                System.out.println("customer eat!");
            }

        };

        human.eat();
        human.x = 10;   //Illegal
        human.test();   //Illegal
    }
}
```

In this code why are `human.x=10;` and `human.test(0);` compile errors?

Comment: What is the actual error message you get?

Comment: cannot find symbols x and method test

Comment: Because you declare the variable as being a `Human`. `Human` neither has a `x` field nor a `test` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `Human` does not have either a field `x` or a method `test()` and your variable `human` is defined as that type.

Your anonymous inner class has that field and that method, so you'd need to define the variable as that type. But "anonymous" means it doesn't have a name, so you can't just replace `Human` with that nonexistent name.

However, if you use `var` then the local variable type inference will give the variable the type of that anonymous class, so replacing `Human human = ...` with `var human =`  will make your code compile.

Comment: Can you answer it in code format?

Comment: @DilshanDekumpitiya: if you read the answer, then you'll find that the last sentence contains very explicit instructions of what needs to change in your code. Other than that: no, I prefer to provide understanding rather than handing out code to be mindlessly copied.

Comment: @DilshanDekumpitiya did you even read this answer?

Answer (score 1):

`human` has a compile time type of `Human`, so when using that reference you act access members (be it data members or methods) that aren't defined by the `Human` class.

The fact that you're using an anonymous class is inconsequential - the same compiler errors would occur if you extended `Human` with a named class:

```java
public class SpecialHuman extends Human {
    int x = 10;

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test - anonymous");
    }

    @Override
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("customer eat!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human h = new SpecialHuman();
        human.eat();
        human.x = 10;   //Illegal
        human.test();   //Illegal
}
```